# SHOUTcast XML get with php

Tags: php, shoutcast

I have shoutcast administrator and i need to read xml from that it looks like this

http://SHOUTCAST-IP:PORT/admin.cgi

And i need to login and get the XML Data from http://SHOUTCAST-IP:PORT/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml and do it with php, i have made this script

```
$fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
      fputs($fp, "GET /admin.cgi?pass=".$password."&mode=viewxml HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)\r\n\r\n"); //
      while (!feof($fp)) {
          $content = fgets($fp);
}
```

But it doesn't work, it says `Unauthorised`. How can i fix it ?

Comment: You're mangling your headers a bit.  Why don't you use cURL instead?  Don't re-invent the wheel... no need to use sockets for this directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can use standard $_GET variables to provide `username` and `password` there? Seems quite bad practice!?

I would use cURL to achieve this, it's quick and easy!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SHOUTCAST-IP:PORT/admin.cgi");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You certainly can specify your password as a URL parameter with SHOUTcast.  What's bad practice about it?  It's there as a convenience feature for situations just like this one.  In any case, basic auth also works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

*What about this?*

```
//*********** YOUR FM ***********//
// Begin Configuration
$scdef  =       "YOUR FM"; 
                                        // ABOVE: Default station name to display when server or stream is down
$scip   =       "127.0.0.1";        // ip or url of shoutcast server (DO NOT ADD HTTP:// don't include the port)
$scport =       "5977";              // port of shoutcast server
$scpass =       "mysecretpassword";              // password to shoutcast server

// End Configuration
//*********** YOUR FM ***********//

$scfp = fsockopen("$scip", $scport, &$errno, &$errstr, 30);
 if(!$scfp) {
  $scsuccs=1;
echo''.$scdef.' is Offline';
 }
if($scsuccs!=1){
 fputs($scfp,"GET /admin.cgi?pass=$scpass&mode=viewxml HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: SHOUTcast Song Status (Mozilla Compatible)\r\n\r\n");
 while(!feof($scfp)) {
  $page .= fgets($scfp, 1000);
 }

 // REST OF YOUR CODE BELOW HERE!
```